# Print url to image from profile2 field with mutiple images

Tags: entities

Hello guys i've been trying to figure this out the past 20 hours but i can't.
I want to print som image url's to a link.
I have this code

```
<div id="background-slideshow">
<?php
  $user_fields = user_load(24);
  $profile2 = profile2_load_by_user($user_fields->uid);
  $image = field_get_items('profile2', $profile2['side'], 'field_baggrundsbillede');    
?>
<?php foreach($image as $key=>$value): ?>
 $output = field_view_value('profile2', $profile2['side'], 'field_baggrundsbillede', $image[$key], array(
  'type' => 'image',
  'settings' => array(
    'image_style' => 'thumbnail'
    'image_link' => 'content',
  ),
));
  <div class="test">
   <?php print render($output) ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

But the problem is that it prints the image file, when i want an url.
How can i make that happen?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
<div id="background-slideshow">
  <?php
    $uid = 24;
    $user_fields = user_load($uid);
    //$profile2 = profile2_load_by_user($user_fields->uid);
    $images = field_get_items('user', $user_fields, 'field_baggrundsbillede');    
  ?>
  <?php foreach($images as $key => $image): ?>
    <?php $url = file_create_url($image['uri']); ?>
    <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $url ?>);">
    </div>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: you are output `theme image` not link in your 4th parameter of `field_view_value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. To get just the path of an image, use [file_create_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_create_url/7)
2. To get the path of an image using an image style, use [image_style_url](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7)

e.g, in the context of your code:

```
<div id="background-slideshow">
<?php
  $uid = 24;
  $user_fields = user_load($uid);
  $profile2 = profile2_load_by_user($user_fields->uid);
  $images = field_get_items('profile2', $profile2['side'], 'field_baggrundsbillede');    
?>
<?php foreach($images as $key => $image): ?>
  $url = file_create_url($image['uri']);
  // $url = image_style_url('medium', $image['uri']); // example image style url
  <div class="test">
   <?php print $url; ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much i've tried with the file_create_url but i couldn't make it show.
So thank you so much

Comment: I modified my code a bit and now it gives me an error
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in include() (line 8 of /home/www/modeindeks.com/sites/all/themes/modeindeks/templates/page.tpl.php).
can you please take a look again, i've made an edit in my question